# Open a new activity to play item on listitemclick

Tags: android, listview, onclick, playback

I have a list of files in a directory. In the activity shown below, the app loads the files into a listview. Now, I need each list item to open it's corresponding file in the directory and play the file in another activity (probably via an intent). Even the test Toast notification does not show up. How can I go about this? This list dynamically changes because it keeps growing each time a new file is added in the directory. So, I can't use a switch-case block easily.

```
public class ReadFilesFromPath extends Activity {
/** Called when the activity is first created. */
List<String> myList;
File file;
ListView listview;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.recordinglist);
listview = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.recordlist);
myList = new ArrayList<String>();

File directory = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
file = new File( directory + "/" + "Recordify" );
File list[] = file.listFiles();

for( int i=0; i< list.length; i++)
{
        myList.add( list[i].getName() );
}
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
        android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, android.R.id.text1, myList);
listview.setAdapter(adapter); //Set all the file in the list.
}
public void onitemclick() {
    listview.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> a, View v, int i,
                long l) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Test", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

    });
 }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem is because you're setting the `onCLickListener()` in a method that isn't called. You should be setting the listener after the `ListView` has been initialized, and calling the method to do your stuff (Or doing it withing the `onItemClick` override method).

So in your `onCreate` you could change it to this:

```
listview = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.recordlist);
listview.setOnItemClickListener(...);
```

Comment: Okay, so I've done that but now the problem still persists. I don't know how to make each item in the list play the file it is showing.

Comment: So at this point, the test toast should show right?
Just pass the position of the the list item being touched, to a method or something. And then in the method do something to display the content based on the position passed.
(From the code you provided, the position is the `int i`)